# pydantic exclude multiple fields from model

Tags: python, model, backend, fastapi, pydantic

In pydantic is there a cleaner way to exclude multiple fields from the model, something  like:

```py
class User(UserBase):
    class Config:        
        exclude = ['user_id', 'some_other_field']
```

I am aware that following works.

```py
class User(UserBase):

    class Config:       
        fields = {'user_id': {'exclude':True}, 
                   'some_other_field': {'exclude':True}
                 }
```

but I was looking for something cleaner like django rest framework, where you could just specify a list of  exclude or include per.

Comment: I came here looking for a clean solution for excluding fields from the OpenAPI description generated by Pydantic 2 but found there doesn't seem to be much native support. The docs say that you need to implement `__get_pydantic_json_schema__` which isn't too hard but does require about 3 different imports from the bowels of Pydantic. [https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/json_schema/#modifying-the-schema](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/json_schema/#modifying-the-schema)

Comment: I don't know how I missed it before but [Pydantic 2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes) uses `typing.ClassVar` so that "Attributes annotated with `typing.ClassVar` are properly treated by Pydantic as class variables, and will not become fields on model instances". So just wrap the field type with `ClassVar` e.g. instead of `foo: int = 1` use `foo: ClassVar[int] = 1`. So this excludes fields from the model, and the schema, but it also removes the field from instances, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 13):

Pydantic will exclude the class variables which begin with an underscore.
so if it fits your use case, you can rename your attribues.

```
class User(UserBase):
    _user_id=str
    some_other_field=str
    ....
```

Comment: one possible issue is that strict type validation doesn't work for class variables with an underscore. you can pass a non-string to `_user_id` and it can cause the code to break somewhere you don't expect

Comment: I found,, using Pydantic 2, that Pydantic throws an error during model creation when underscores are used: "NameError: Fields must not use names with leading underscores; e.g., use 'correlation_id' instead of '_correlation_id'."

Comment: Per the newest FastAPI docs:  “As of Pydantic v2.1.0, you will receive a NameError if trying to use the Field function with a private attribute. Because private attributes are not treated as fields, the Field() function cannot be applied.” @NeilG Try using PrivateAttr() instead. https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#fields-with-non-hashable-default-values

Comment: Thanks @pythlang, but unfortunately I want some field behaviour, but I just don't want them appearing in the OpenAPI description. They're secret internal fields. I used a similar approach to that here except I created them as fields with a description string of `"__exclude__"`.. I then interrupted the OpenAPI JSON dump to look for that description and delete those fields. A bit hacky and no better than the question here but it seems to be the prudent route for my use-case.

Answer (score 9):

To exclude a field you can also use `exclude` in `Field`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Mdl(BaseModel):
    val: str = Field(
        exclude=True,
        title="val"
    )
```

however, the advantage of adding excluded parameters in the `Config` class seems to be that you can get the list of excluded parameters with

```
print(Mdl.Config.exclude)
```

Comment: This doesn't work with version `2.6.1`

Comment: This answer was tested with `pydantic < 2`, so they might have changed something in version 2

Answer (score 7):

I wrote something like this for my json :

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class CustomBase(BaseModel):
    def json(self, **kwargs):
        include = getattr(self.Config, "include", set())
        if len(include) == 0:
            include = None
        exclude = getattr(self.Config, "exclude", set())
        if len(exclude) == 0:
            exclude = None
        return super().json(include=include, exclude=exclude, **kwargs)

    

class User(CustomBase):
    name :str = ...
    family :str = ...

    class Config:
        exclude = {"family"}


u = User(**{"name":"milad","family":"vayani"})

print(u.json())
```

you can overriding dict and other method like.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is creating a new class based in the baseclass using create_model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

def exclude_id(baseclass, to_exclude: list):
    # Here we just extract the fields and validators from the baseclass
    fields = baseclass.__fields__
    validators = {'__validators__': baseclass.__validators__}
    new_fields = {key: (item.type_, ... if item.required else None)
                  for key, item in fields.items() if key not in to_exclude}
    return create_model(f'{baseclass.__name__}Excluded', **new_fields, __validators__=validators)


class User(BaseModel):
    ID: str
    some_other: str

list_to_exclude = ['ID']
UserExcluded = exclude_id(User, list_to_exclude)

UserExcluded(some_other='hola')
```

Which will return:

```
> UserExcluded(some_other='hola')
```

Which is a copy of the baseclass but with no parameter 'ID'.

If you have the id in the validators you may want also to exclude those validators.

Comment: You need to add __config__=baseclass.__config__ that include Config in new model. For example, it is very important when you use orm_mode=True etc

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it in the field level or when serializing the model ([see docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#advanced-include-and-exclude)). Currently there is a stale issue for having include / exclude in the [model_config](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/660).

```py
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class A(BaseModel):
    foo: str = Field('bar', exclude=True)
    bar: Annotated[int, Field(exclude=True)] = 'bar'
    baz: str = 'bar'

a = A()
assert 'baz' not in a.model_dump(exclude={'baz'})
assert 'baz' in a.model_dump()
assert 'foo' not in a.model_dump()
```

Answer (score 0):

For pydantic2 you can use do something like:

```
class User(UserBase):
    user_id: Annotated[int, Field(exclude=True)] 
    some_other_field: str
```

This can be much cleaner